# Marketing Cloud Query - 7 days before the start date

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I am writing a query that will add people into the data extension if the event is starting in 1 week time. So the idea is to trigger the reminder email 1 week before the event.

The snippet of query is below:

```
Select * where start_date = DATEPART(dd, DATEADD(dd,-7,GETDATE()))
```

The query works fine. But the issue is I need to add 10 hours to offset the US server time so that it will match my local time.

For other date related qeuires I have been doing this

```
start_date = DATEPART(dd, DATEADD(hh,10,GETDATE()))
```

How can I combine these two so that I can add the people 7 days before the event into DE and also consider the time difference?

Comment: Why are you using `5` as opposed to `7` in your `DATEADD`

Comment: Hi @Data_Kid, it should be 7. I have edited the typo error.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `start_date` in hours in the first one i.e `610` (if you are ahead) or `590` (10 hours behind).

```
/* 10 Hours Ahead */
SELECT  * 
FROM [Data_Extension]
where 
start_date = DATEPART(dd, DATEADD(hh,-590,GETDATE()))

/* 10 Hours Behind */
SELECT  * 
FROM [Data_Extension]
where 
start_date = DATEPART(dd, DATEADD(hh,-610,GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Thanks. It did not work for me. Without the date filter, I got some records in my DE. But after adding date filter, no records returns.

Answer (score 1):

I generally do these types of queries like this:

```
select
de.name
, de.start_date
from [Data_Extension] de
where de.start_date >= convert(date, getDate()-7)
and de.start_date < convert(date, getDate()-6)
```

This method of doing the date criteria handles the time portions of the dates properly and is more efficient ([sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799616/812377)) than using multiple date functions.  You can simply subtract days from `getDate()` without another function.

Also, I'd advise against using `select *` in your queries.  The column names are cached, so if you add a column later, it may not get selected in your query.